# TypeScript 1.6 error: JSX element type XXX does not have any construct or call signature

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, typescript1.6

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
          render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                Hello, world!I am a CommentList.
                </div>
        );
          }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
          render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList /> //ERROR
                </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
          React.createElement(CommentBox, null),
          document.getElementById('content')
);
```

With this code, I get the following error message:
**JSX element type 'CommentList' does not have any construct or call signatures.**

The same code works with plain HTML/JS (following this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)

I have no clue why TypeScript doesn't like it.
Using Visual Studio 2013 with TS 1.6 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx)

Comment: Strange. Works fine for me when compiling from the command line with 1.6.2.

Comment: Typescript installs were very bad. I had Typescript/ Typescript/1.2/ Typescript/1.3/ Typescript/1.4 all in my Environment Path. You may not be referencing 1.6 when you think you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine without error (screen shot from atom-typescript) :

[image]

Suggestions:

- Make sure visual studio is truly using typescript 1.6
- Make sure you have `react.d.ts` included and try not to use the global version
- Make sure you have the `React` variable available (e.g. `import React = require('react');`).

Comment: I figured it out ... I loaded the react.d.ts file via NuGet "React.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped (V 0.1.12) ... I updated it with this version: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts